# C# How to hit a method in debug

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Probably not a good title, and this question might be stupid, but I really have no idea how to do this.

I've created a project that connects to a DB with EF Core . I've created my DbContext class and my Repository class that does the actual querying .

Then I created another class , maybe I created it wrong, but I made it similar to a controller of an MVC project . This is my class:

```
    public class ExtractCustomersToBeMarked
    {
        private ICampaignRepository _repository;
        private ILogger<ExtractCustomersToBeMarked> _logger;

        public ExtractCustomersToBeMarked(ILogger<ExtractCustomersToBeMarked> logger, ICampaignRepository repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;
            _logger = logger;
        }
        public async Task ExtractCustomers()
        {
            IEnumerable<CampaignKnownCustomers> result = _repository.getCustomersGUID();               
           ... I want to debug this code
        }
    }
```

Now I want to debug my program . I tried calling the method from my Main program , but with no success as I don't know what to pass to the constructor (MVC does that on its own) . That's what I tried :

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p = new Program();
         p.Run().Wait();
    }
    private async Task Run()
    {
        ExtractCustomersToBeMarked ectm = new ExtractCustomersToBeMarked(?,?);
        await ExtractCustomersToBeMarked.ExtractCustomers();
    }
```

I know it doesn't look good, this structure is simply for debugging . If theres another way I'm open to hear about it..

How can I hit the debugger on `ExtractCustomers`?

Comment: You pass in the implemented ILogger and ICampaignRepository concrete classes ? Since you created it you should know?

Comment: create a unit test with mocked implementations of your dependecies

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have implemented a `CampaignRepository` class. Provided that you want to use this implementation when debugging the `ExtractCustomers()` method, you should simply create an instance of it and pass to the method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   ExtractCustomersToBeMarked ectm = new ExtractCustomersToBeMarked(null, new CampaignRepository());
   ectm.ExtractCustomers().Wait();
}
```

The same goes for the logger. Create an instance of a class that implements the `ILogger<ExtractCustomersToBeMarked>` if you use the logger in the method that you want to debug. Don't forget to pass it to the constructor of the `ExtractCustomersToBeMarked` class when you create an instance of it.

You may want to implement an integration test instead of modifying the `Main()` method of the application itself though but that's another story.

Answer (score 0):

**Summary** I'd suggest writing Unit Tests against the code you want to debug.

**Detail** When you have Unit Tests in place you can run each individual test under Debug, allowing you to step through the code exactly like you do when debugging the application; but with the benefit that you get to define the scope and context of the test, for example you can test isolated parts of your system independently of others.

Once a test is in place, it can shorten the time taken by the code+debug iteration cycle, making you more productive. It achieves that because the test fires you straight into the relevant code with the test scenario already set up, rather than the whole application having to start up, and you navigating through to the relevant parts each time to get into the scenario you want.

Another benefit of these tests (if they are written the right way) is that you can make them run as part of an automated build which is triggered whenever someone changes some code. This means that if anyone breaks that code, the test will fail, and the build will fail.